# When to decline welche?

Tags: pronoun

I am studying **welche** and **Diese** and I don't know how to decline to the nominative and accusative forms. I only know that nominative is related to  direct object (*C.O.D* in French) and that accusative is related to indirect object (*C.O.I*).

> La mère de Grégoire. (*Grégoire's mother*).
>
> Grégoire parle à sa mère (*Grégoire talks to his mother*).

I don't know which form to use when having :

> Sieh mal, die Jacke ist doch toll!:
>
> - Welche?
> - Welches?

It looks like a direct object so I would have said "Welche".

**But what if the adj. pron. "welche" was at the begining? Would it be different?**

> Welch*er* Anzug ist besser?

Otherwise, I don't know when Welche is in the accusative form. I have only studied the language form one year.

Comment: I guess you meant to say "dative" whenever you wrote "nominative", didn't you? Because the "direct object" is usually the dative. — On the other hand, your example is in nominative case, indeed.

Comment: @Em1, accusative, right?

Comment: @CarstenS Darn. Of course. I didn't notice that the whole second sentence is incorrect. Direct object ~ accusative and indirect object ~ dative. — And I didn't realise that the first example is neither one. The premise is entirely wrong, I'm afraid.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/welcher

Answer (score 6):

The point of matter is the gender of the noun.
In the German language, a noun can be feminine, masculine or neutral.

> - die Jacke = weiblich = feminine
> - der Anzug = männlich = masculine
> - das Auto = neutral = neutral

Now take for each gender the corresponding interrogative:

> - **Die** Jacke ist doch toll. **Welche** Jacke ist toll? *or* **Welche** Jacke?
> - **Der** Anzug ist besser. **Welcher** Anzug ist besser? *or* **Welcher** Anzug?
> - **Das** Auto ist schnell. **Welches** Auto ist schnell? *or* **Welches** Auto?

To this questions one can anwser with *diese/dieser/dieses* in the same manner:

> - **Die** Jacke ist doch toll. **Welche** Jacke? **Diese** Jacke.
> - **Der** Anzug ist besser. **Welcher** Anzug? **Dieser** Anzug.
> - **Das** Auto ist schnell. **Welches** Auto? **Dieses** Auto.

Is this the answer you were searching for?

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker I am sure in saying that the declination of "welche" is mainly dependent on the grammatical gender and the case of the noun "welche/r/s" refers to. The position of the word is not relevant.

When referring to a noun in nominative case, this is how you apply "Welche/r/s":

"Welch*e*" is used when referring to a plural noun or nouns of feminine grammatical gender.

"Welch*er*" is used for male nouns.

"Welch*es*" is used for neuter nouns.

Referring to an accusative noun, declination is the same for feminine nouns; only male nouns are used differently; "Welchen" is used there.

> - Markus kaufte sich heute einen Anzug, welch*en* er gleich anzog.
> - Welch*en* Anzug fand Markus so toll?

I hope this helped!

Comment: Fixed. Any other objections?

Comment: Fixed, too. If there is anything else to criticize, don't be shy to tell, I am open for learning how to improve my posts here.

Answer (score 1):

There is, unfortunately, no way around identifying a noun’s gender *and* case in the sentence in question when determining which form of *welche* and *diese* is correct.

> Sieh mal, die Jacke<sup>{Nom. Fem. Sing.}</sup> ist doch toll!
>
> **Welche**<sup>{Nom. Fem. Sing.}</sup> Jacke?
>
> **Diese**<sup>{Nom. Fem. Sing.}</sup> Jacke.
>
> ---
>
> Wollen Sie den Anzug<sup>{Akk. Mask. Sing.}</sup> kaufen?
>
> **Welchen**<sup>{Akk. Mask. Sing.}</sup> Anzug?
>
> **Diesen**<sup>{Akk. Mask. Sing.}</sup> Anzug.
>
> ---
>
> Magst du dich in **diesem**<sup>{Dat. Mask. Sing.}</sup> oder in **diesem** Spiegel<sup>{Dat. Mask. Sing.}</sup> anschauen?
>
> In **welchem**<sup>{Dat. Mask. Sing.}</sup> Spiegel? Ich sehe keinen.
>
> ---
>
> Die Katze des Hofs<sup>{Gen. Mask. Sing.}</sup> ist gestern gestorben.
>
> **Welches**<sup>{Gen. Mask. Sing.}</sup> Hofs?
>
> ---
>
> Gefällt Ihnen das Auto<sup>{Nom. Neut. Sing.}</sup>?
>
> **Welches**<sup>{Nom. Neut. Sing.}</sup> Auto?
>
> ---
>
> Mögen Sie Brote<sup>{Akk. Neut. Plur.}</sup>?
>
> **Welche**<sup>{Akk. Neut. Plur.}</sup> Brote?

---

As a side note, you used the termns *direct* and *indirect object.* In German grammar, it is better to use *dative object, accusative object, genitive object* and *prepositional object* to refer to different types of object. While there is a large overlap between English and French indirect objects and German dative objects, note that a dative object typically connects to the verb *directly* as a direct object in English and French would. Prepositional objects typically have a case governed by the preposition which can be either dative or accusative.

Finally remember that French direct objects and German accusative objects do not match perfectly. Consider the verb *aider qn* which in French has a direct object and its translation *jemande**m** helfen* which in German requires dative.